# NSAttributedString: image not showing up in UILabel

Tags: swift, uiimage, uilabel, nsattributedstring

For some reason, the image does not display.  I have dropped test.png and test@2x.png both under Image.xcassets/  I also dropped it within the project.  None of that helped.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
    var testView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, self.view.frame.width-40, self.view.frame.height-40))
 var a = "Testing..."

    var attachment = NSTextAttachment()
    //This is the image that I would like to add 
    // I have dropped test.png and test@2x.png under Image.xcassets

    attachment.image = UIImage(named: "test")

    var attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
    let attrsB = NSAttributedString(
        string: "2nd line..Testing testing",
        attributes: NSDictionary(
            object: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 18.0)!,
            forKey: NSFontAttributeName) as [NSObject : AnyObject])



    a.appendAttributedString(attrsB)
    let attributedTextToDisplay = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: a)

    attributedTextToDisplay.appendAttributedString(attachmentString)

    testView.attributedText = attributedTextToDisplay

    self.view.addSubview(testView)
```

Comment: *I also dropped it within the project*: Not necessary if already in an `Assets Catalog`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow your label to have multiple lines if you want to display more than 1 line.

```
var testView: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(20, 20, self.view.frame.width-40, self.view.frame.height-40))
testView.numberOfLines = 0;
```

---

Tips:

1. Use Storyboard & Interface Builder. WYSIWYG.
2. Use AutoLayout, it solves a lot of resizing for you
3. Use *asserts* if you are unsure of the content of a variable
4. Step into debugger and push on the eye icon to reveal *quicklook*
5. Eliminating all these variables will help you find out the root cause, and not worry, say, about whether or not your image is loaded. See sample below.

For good measures, I also explicitly typed `a` into a `a:NSMutableAttributedString`.

```
var a:NSMutableAttributedString
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I just spent some more time on it patiently : ) and the issue is resolved.

Comment: Great. You may find that in writing iOS Apps, coding is actually the enemy: the more you user GUI Interface Builder, and all modern tools, the less bugs you will encounter. +1 ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue when I used `didSet {}` on the `IBOutlet`, moving the code to `ViewDidLoad()` method solved it.